# What is the practicality of using sub-cooled propane in combination with HTP in an amateur engine design?

Tags: fuel, engine-design, amateur-rocketry

Using sub-cooled propane, at approximately -90°C (b.p. -42°C at STP) in combination with >80% hydrogen peroxide, can any meaningful gains be made, whilst considering that this fuel mixture would be used in an amateur engine design?

As well as this, what O/F ratio would be optimal for this fuel/oxidizer combination, and could these two liquids be stored at a common temperature, using additives to lower the [HTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-test_peroxide)'s melting point?

Comment: @uhoh yeah no I just mean in a tank that shares a common wall or something similar not actually mixing the two in one common tank- I can only see that ending badly

Comment: Got it, I've made a small adjustment to the wording then, feel free to roll back or edit further. Interesting question btw!

Comment: As much as I want to answer these delightful questions about building your own rocket engines, it might not be appropiate for this site: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/why-cant-i-ask-my-question-about-amateur-space-projects-and-development

Comment: @ReubenFarley-Hall I agree with Anton Hengst.

Comment: Amateur liquid fuel rockets of any kind are somewhat practicality challenged in the first place.